# C# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Overflow'

Tags: c#, oledb

[image: Access Database]

I'm fairly new to using C# and I cannot seem to get this insert statement to work. Any help would be appreciated. I am trying to insert text Box, check Box, and date Time Picker values into an Access Data Base using Ole DB. I run the user entered information through Fluent Validation for validation before the insert statement.

```
private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        errors.Clear();

        if(!decimal.TryParse(textBoxPayRate.Text, out decimal payRate))
        {
            errors.Add("Pay Rate: Invalid Amount"); 
            return;
        }

        EmployeeModel employee = new EmployeeModel();
        employee.FirstName = textBoxFirstName.Text;
        employee.LastName = textBoxLastName.Text;
        employee.PhoneNumber = textBoxPhone.Text;
        employee.DateHired = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        employee.PayRate = payRate;
        employee.Employed = checkBoxEmployed.Checked;

        //Validate data and list error in listBoxError
        EmployeeValidator validator = new EmployeeValidator();

        ValidationResult results = validator.Validate(employee);

        if(results.IsValid == false)
        {
            foreach (ValidationFailure failure in results.Errors)
            {
                errors.Add(failure.ErrorMessage);
            }
        }
        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\EmployeeInfo1.mdb";
        
        connection.Open();
        
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT into EmployeeData ([firstName], [lastName], [Phone], [Employed], [dateHired], [payRate])VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateHired", OleDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@payRate", OleDbType.Currency).Value = textBoxPayRate.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employed", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = checkBoxEmployed.Checked;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxPhone.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxLastName.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = textBoxFirstName.Text;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
}
```

Here is my validation class

```
public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        //Validiation rules for FirstName
        RuleFor(p => p.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is Empty")
            .Length(2, 50).WithMessage("Length of {PropertyName} Invalid")
            .Must(BeAValidName).WithMessage("{PropertyName} Contains Invalid Characters");

        //Validiation rules for LastName
        RuleFor(p => p.LastName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is Empty")
            .Length(2, 50).WithMessage("Length of {PropertyName} Invalid")
            .Must(BeAValidName).WithMessage("{PropertyName} Contains Invalid Characters");

        //Validiation rules for PhoneNumber
        RuleFor(p => p.PhoneNumber)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is Empty")
            .Length(10).WithMessage("Length of {PropertyName} Invalid")
            .Must(BeAValidPhone).WithMessage("{PropertyName} Contains Invalid Characters");

        //Validation rules for Pay Rate
        RuleFor(p => p.PayRate)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("{PropertyName} is Empty");
            
        //Validiation for hired date
        RuleFor(p => p.DateHired)
            .Must(BeAValidDate).WithMessage("Invalid {PropertyName}");
    }

    protected bool BeAValidName(string name)
    {
        name = name.Replace(" ", "");
        name = name.Replace("-", "");
        return name.All(Char.IsLetter);
    }

    protected bool BeAValidPhone(string digit)
    {
        return digit.All(Char.IsDigit);
    }

    protected bool BeAValidDate(DateTime date)
    {
        int currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
        int hireYear = date.Year;

        if(hireYear <= currentYear && hireYear > (currentYear - 70))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: OleDB parameters have to be in the same order as they appear in the sql statement since they don't use a key.

Comment: And that fixed it. Thank you @LarsTech